# Vertical CSS Multi-Level Menu That Positions Itself at the Top of the div, not at the 1st Menu Option's Position

Tags: html, css

Most CSS vertical menus have their second level and third layer menus popping out right beside the 1st level menu. This creates a space if you go to the third option in the first level menu. The second level menu from that third option is positioned only as high as the third menu first level item. Thus, there's a space above the second level menu, all the way up to the first level menu first selection.

How would I go about making it so that the second level menu that pops out would be at the highest first level menu selection?

I made a graphic to further iterate this.

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmQSI.png

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIZxJ.png

In the first image, when you hover over Purchase, the menu pops out to the side. Instead, I want the menu to pop out above, at the Products area. I want it so that even if I go to Products, Purchase, Support, Downloads...etc, that second level menu ALWAYS pops out at the top of the menu/Products.

In my actual menu, each level will only have four options, so there will be no issues hovering over and keeping the menu active.

Does anyone have a link or an idea on how to get this done?

Thanks - and I hope I explained it well..lol.

EDIT:

*I took this off of a website, I realize there's a ton of syntax errors like missing quotes and such. I'm just trying to get it to work before I fix anything and refine it.
CSS

```
#menu ul { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    list-style: none;
    width: 150px; /* Width of Menu Items */ 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
} 

#menu ul li { 
    position: relative; 
} 

#menu li ul { 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 149px; /*Set 1px less than menu width */ 
    top: 0; 
    display: block; 
} 

#menu li:hover ul {
    display: block; 
} 

#menu li:hover>ul { 
    visibility:visible; 
} 

#menu ul ul {
    visibility:hidden; 
} 

/* Fix IE. Hide from IE Mac \*/ 
* html #menu ul li { float: left; height: 1%; } 
* html #menu ul li a { height: 1%; } 
/* End */ 

/* Make-up syles */ 

#menu ul, li { 
    margin: 0 0 0 0; 
} 

/* Styles for Menu Items */ 
#menu ul a { 
    display: block; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #777; 
    background: #fff; /* IE6 Bug */ 
    padding: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    border-bottom: 0; 
} 

/* Hover Styles */ 
#menu ul a:hover { 
    color: #E2144A; 
    background: #f9f9f9; 
} 

/* Sub Menu Styles */ 
#menu li ul a { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #77F; 
    background: #fff; /* IE6 Bug */ 
    padding: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    border-bottom: 0; 
} 

/* Sub Menu Hover Styles */ 
#menu li ul a:hover { 
    color: #E2144A; 
    background: #f9f9f9; 
} 

/* Icon Styles */ 
#menu ul a.submenu {background:#fff url("r_arrow.gif") no-repeat right; } 
#menu ul a.submenu:hover {background:#f9f9f9 url("r_arrow.gif") no-repeat right;}
```

html:

```
    <div id=menu>
    <ul id=menuList>
        <li><a href="#" name="submenu" class="submenu">Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">All</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">CodeCharge</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">CodeCharge Studio</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">DemoCharge Studio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" name="submenu" class="submenu">Comparison</a><ul>
                        <li><a href="#">CodeCharge Studio</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#">DemoCharge Studio</a></li>
                    </ul></li> 
            </ul>
        </li> 
        <li><a href="#" name="submenu" class="submenu">Downloads</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">CodeCharge</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">CodeCharge Studio</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">DemoCharge Studio</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li> 
        <li><a href="#" name="submenu" class="submenu">Support</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://support.yessoftware.com">Support</a></li> 
                <li><a href="http://forums.codecharge.com">Forums</a></li> 
                <li><a href="http://support.yessoftware.com/kb_search.asp">KB</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li> 
        <li><a href="#" name="submenu" class="submenu">Purchase</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Store</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Resellers</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Affiliate</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li> 
        <li><a href="#" name="submenu" class="submenu">Company</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Press Releases</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

IE Fix:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
startList = function() {

    // code for IE
    if(!document.body.currentStyle) return;
    var subs = document.getElementsByName('submenu');
    for(var i=0; i<subs.length; i++) {
        var li = subs[i].parentNode;
        if(li && li.lastChild.style) {
            li.onmouseover = function() {
                this.lastChild.style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
            li.onmouseout = function() {
                this.lastChild.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
        }
    }
}
window.onload=startList;
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure how you have positioned (relative, static, etc) them but have you tried 'top:0' or margin-top:**whatever the negative needs to be for each one** (Requires identifying individually)

Comment: If you provide some code I may be able to help further

Comment: I added the code in the main post. I did take the code from a website, and realize there's issues with the syntax and other stuff. I'm just trying to get it to work right now and will definitely take care of the refinement later.

Comment: This is a personal comment, but why would you want to do that?

Comment: I am making a VoD system and do not want to use frames. :D
Open to using Javascript if need be, or php, but something pure-css would be magnificent. Haven't been able to find any tutorials or discussions about it, so I am interested in knowing if it possible.

Comment: But it breaks the normal way that most users would expect a fly-out menu to act.

Comment: If I get this working I will provide a screenshot of how it looks and acts. With how things are positioned, the user will expect it to work as I am wanting it to. Any other way would break the flow of the site, so they can't mentally anticipate it to work any other way.

Comment: I'm with @Jared Farrish on this... it makes no sense... how do you even get your mouse into the submenu without it closing first?

Comment: Because there is only 4 menus every single time. As long as you stay on one of those 4 menus that pop out the menu will remain active and won't collapse.

The menu just keeps getting longer, not lower.

Comment: Yes but the trouble you have is that the menu will change when you mouse over the another menu item, so it doesnt really work, not without lots more fiddling

Comment: If I read that right, then if the person moved to another menu item, it would be because they wanted to select something different from what menu they are currently in. It also wouldn't collapse the entire menu if you were 3+ levels in.

When I get it done, I will show a demonstration of it. Hopefully it'll make everything make more sense.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood your comment. You are correct, with 4 menu items for each menu, it will be fine.

Comment: Justin, it's hard to see at this point how the menu system you're describing is better than a regular fly-out, but I'll reserve judgment. What I'm wondering is if using `ul`'s embedded is the best approach; when, if you think about it in the abstract, `float`ed elements in relation to each other is possibly what you're after. You may need to abandon the normal menu construct, while also considering the challenges raised here when a mouse moves away from an element.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/tQFLA.png

Don't know how useful this will be in showing how useful this style of a menu is for my design. If there are better alternatives and that is why it is hard to visualize the usefulness of this menu, then let me know what those alternatives are, lol. :)

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS, change `#menu ul` to `position: relative`:

```
#menu ul
{ 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    width: 150px; /* Width of Menu Items */ 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
```

And remove the relative positioning from `#menu ul li`:

```
#menu ul li
{ 
    /*position: relative;*/
}
```

This makes it a little difficult to get over to the subitems, though.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KvaTC/

Comment: *This makes it a little difficult to get over to the subitems, though.* +1

Comment: This works, thank you! I had no idea which values to change or remove. But alas, it makes so much more sense now. :)

Comment: Im sorry but am i missing something here? going to relative is pushing the first menu items apart because the height of the submenu items are being recognised.

Comment: Lol I must be tired, I am missing comments all over the shop here... Thanks for pointing that out to me, I was going screwy trying to figure out why. This is how to do it... +1

Answer (score 1):

If you give each ul that is a submenu an id, then you can specify in CSS for that ID a negative top value of whatever is necessary for each one.  I would recommend setting a height value for the li tags concerned for two reasons, it will tell every browser to render them at the same height and you can calculate the negatives required - no javascript required to do this.

So, take out the top:0 in the following code block so it is like this:

```
#menu li ul { 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 149px; /*Set 1px less than menu width */ 
  display: block; 
}
```

Then set a height for each li concerned:

```
#menu ul li { 
  position: relative; 
  height:30px;
}
```

Then for each submenu ul give an id (I show the first one as an example):

```
<ul id=menuList>
    <li><a href="#" name="submenu" class="submenu">Products</a>
        <ul id="submenu1">
            <li><a href="#">All</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">CodeCharge</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">CodeCharge Studio</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">DemoCharge Studio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" name="submenu" class="submenu">Comparison</a><ul>
                    <li><a href="#">CodeCharge Studio</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">DemoCharge Studio</a></li>
                </ul></li> 
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Then the CSS:

```
#submenu1 {
  top:0px;
}
```

Each subsequent id would then need negative values for whatever is required for them to be at the top. so for the second, now they have a definite height of 30px would be:

```
#submenu2 {
  top:-30px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Psyrus/C3xqX/

Comment: I see. I will try this method out and get it working. I'll save it in case the other solution falls through in the future! Thanks, it is also great to learn from too.